# Cloning the code with a button gives clone.appendChild error

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a seperate button for every line that clones the code and creates a new drop-down menu and user input field. I've been getting this error message "TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'container.appendChild')".

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <script src="javadrive.js"></script>
</head>
<p id="demo">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    const food = '{"ananas":"255","avokado":"1981","banane":"790","borovnice":"845","breskve":"910","češnje":"1411","datlji":"2277","figa":"3360","grozdje":"608","hruške":"922","jabolka":"822","jagode":"347","kivi":"514","kokos":"2687","kosmulje":"526","limone":"642","lubenica":"235","maline":"413","mandarine":"748","marelica":"1287","melona":"962","nektarine":"910","papaja":"460","pomaranče":"560","robide":"962","slive":"2180","artičoka":"819","brokoli":"285","brstični_ohrovt":"285","buča":"336","cvetača":"285","čebula":"272","česen":"589","čičirika":"4177","fižol":"2018","gobe":"322","grah":"585","kisle_kumarice":"353","korenček":"195","koruza":"1222","krompir":"287","kumara":"353","ohrovt":"322","paradižnik":"214","repa":"195","sladek_krompir":"383","solata":"237","šparglji":"2150","špinača":"292","zelje":"280","indijski_oreščki":"14218","kostanj":"2750","lešnik":"5258","mandelj":"16095","oreh":"4918","pistacije":"11363","indijski_oreščki":"14218","kostanj":"2750","lešnik":"5258","mandelj":"16095","oreh":"4918","pistacije":"11363","ječmen":"1423","kruh":"1608","oves":"1788","proso":"4478","pšenica":"1827","riž":"2497","rž":"1544","testenine":"1849","govedina":"15415","jagnjetina":"5301","konjsko":"51779","kozje":"8763","ovčetina":"8763","perutnina":"4325","slanina":"6238","svinjina":"5988","šunka":"5677","jajca":"3265","jogurt":"1186","kefir":"1599","maslo":"5553","mleko":"1020","pinjenec":"1599","sir":"5060","tofu":"2145"}'
    const objs = JSON.parse(food);

  </script>
</p>

<label for="sadje">Izberi sadje:</label>
<select name="sadje" id="sadje">
  <option value="ananas">ananas</option>
  <option value="avokado">avokado</option>
  <option value="banane">banane</option>
  <option value="borovnice">borovnice</option>
  <option value="breskve">breskve</option>
  <option value="češnje">češnje</option>
  <option value="datlji">datlji</option>
  <option value="figa">figa</option>
  <option value="grozdje">grozdje</option>
  <option value="hruške">hruške</option>
  <option value="jabolka">jabolka</option>
  <option value="jagode">jagode</option>
  <option value="kivi">kivi</option>
  <option value="kokos">kokos</option>
  <option value="kosmulje">kosmulje</option>
  <option value="limone">limone</option>
  <option value="lubenica">lubenica</option>
  <option value="maline">maline</option>
  <option value="mandarine">mandarine</option>
  <option value="marelica">marelica</option>
  <option value="saab">melona</option>
  <option value="nektarine">nektarine</option>
  <option value="papaja">papaja</option>
  <option value="pomaranče">pomaranče</option>
  <option value="robide">robide</option>
  <option value="slive">slive</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="skolicina" />g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('sadje','skolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
<label for="zelenjava">Izberi zelenjavo:</label>
<select name="zelenjava" id="zelenjava">
  <option value="artičoka">artičoka</option>
  <option value="brokoli">brokoli</option>
  <option value="brstični_ohrovt">brstični ohrovt</option>
  <option value="buča">buča</option>
  <option value="cvetača">cvetača</option>
  <option value="čebula">čebula</option>
  <option value="česen">česen</option>
  <option value="čičirika">čičirika</option>
  <option value="fižol">fižol</option>
  <option value="gobe">gobe</option>
  <option value="grah">grah</option>
  <option value="kisle_kumarice">kisle kumarice</option>
  <option value="korenček">korenček</option>
  <option value="koruza">koruza</option>
  <option value="krompir">krompir</option>
  <option value="kumara">kumara</option>
  <option value="ohrovt">ohrovt</option>
  <option value="paradižnik">paradižnik</option>
  <option value="repa">repa</option>
  <option value="sladek_krompir">sladek krompir</option>
  <option value="solata">solata</option>
  <option value="šparglji">šparglji</option>
  <option value="špinača">špinača</option>
  <option value="zelje">zelje</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="zkolicina" />g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('zelenjava','zkolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
<label for="oreščki">Izberi oreščke:</label>
<select name="oreščki" id="oreščki">
  <option value="indijski_oreščki">indijski oreščki</option>
  <option value="kostanj">kostanj</option>
  <option value="lešnik">lešnik</option>
  <option value="mandelj">mandelj</option>
  <option value="oreh">oreh</option>
  <option value="pistacije">pistacije</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="okolicina" />g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('oreščki','okolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
<label for="žitarice">Izberi žitarico:</label>
<select name="žitarice" id="žitarice">
  <option value="ječmen">ječmen</option>
  <option value="kruh">kruh</option>
  <option value="oves">oves</option>
  <option value="proso">proso</option>
  <option value="pšenica">pšenica</option>
  <option value="riž">riž</option>
  <option value="rž">rž</option>
  <option value="testenine">testenine</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="žkolicina" />g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('žitarice','žkolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
<label for="meso">Izberi meso:</label>
<select name="meso" id="meso">
  <option value="govedina">govedina</option>
  <option value="jagnjetina">jagnjetina</option>
  <option value="konjsko">konjsko meso</option>
  <option value="kozje">kozje meso</option>
  <option value="ovčetina">ovčetina</option>
  <option value="perutnina">perutnina</option>
  <option value="slanina">slanina</option>
  <option value="svinjina">svinjina</option>
  <option value="šunka">šunka</option>
  <option value="jajca">jajca</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="mkolicina">g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('meso','mkolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
<label for="mleko">Izberi mlečni produkt:</label>
<select name="mleko" id="mleko">
  <option value="jogurt">jogurt</option>
  <option value="kefir">kefir</option>
  <option value="maslo">maslo</option>
  <option value="mleko">mleko</option>
  <option value="pinjenec">pinjenec</option>
  <option value="sir">sir</option>
  <option value="tofu">tofu</option>
</select>
Količina: <input type="text" id="mlkolicina" />g
<button type="button" onclick="izracun('mleko','mlkolicina')">izračunaj</button>

<button type="button" onclick="cloneCode1()">Clone Code 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="cloneCode2()">Clone Code 2</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function cloneCode1() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container1");
  var clone = document.createElement("div");
  clone.innerHTML = `
    <label for="sadje">Izberi sadje:</label>
    <select name="sadje" id="sadje">
      <option value="ananas">ananas</option>
      <option value="avokado">avokado</option>
      <option value="banane">banane</option>
      <option value="borovnice">borovnice</option>
      <option value="breskve">breskve</option>
      <option value="češnje">češnje</option>
      <option value="datlji">datlji</option>
      <option value="figa">figa</option>
      <option value="grozdje">grozdje</option>
      <option value="hruške">hruške</option>
      <option value="jabolka">jabolka</option>
      <option value="jagode">jagode</option>
      <option value="kivi">kivi</option>
      <option value="kokos">kokos</option>
      <option value="kosmulje">kosmulje</option>
      <option value="limone">limone</option>
      <option value="lubenica">lubenica</option>
      <option value="maline">maline</option>
      <option value="mandarine">mandarine</option>
      <option value="marelica">marelica</option>
      <option value="saab">melona</option>
      <option value="nektarine">nektarine</option>
      <option value="papaja">papaja</option>
      <option value="pomaranče">pomaranče</option>
      <option value="robide">robide</option>
      <option value="slive">slive</option>
    </select>
    Količina: <input type="text" id="skolicina" />g
    <button type="button" onclick="izracun('sadje','skolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
  `;
  container.appendChild(clone);
}

function cloneCode2() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container2");
  var clone = document.createElement("div");
  clone.innerHTML = `
    <label for="zelenjava">Izberi zelenjavo:</label>
    <select name="zelenjava" id="zelenjava">
      <option value="artičoka">artičoka</option>
      <option value="brokoli">brokoli</option>
      <option value="brstični_ohrovt">brstični ohrovt</option>
      <option value="buča">buča</option>
      <option value="cvetača">cvetača</option>
      <option value="čebula">čebula</option>
      <option value="česen">česen</option>
      <option value="čičirika">čičirika</option>
      <option value="fižol">fižol</option>
      <option value="gobe">gobe</option>
      <option value="grah">grah</option>
      <option value="kisle_kumarice">kisle kumarice</option>
      <option value="korenček">korenček</option>
      <option value="koruza">koruza</option>
      <option value="krompir">krompir</option>
      <option value="kumara">kumara</option>
      <option value="ohrovt">ohrovt</option>
      <option value="paradižnik">paradižnik</option>
      <option value="repa">repa</option>
      <option value="sladek_krompir">sladek krompir</option>
      <option value="solata">solata</option>
      <option value="šparglji">šparglji</option>
      <option value="špinača">špinača</option>
      <option value="zelje">zelje</option>
    </select>
    Količina: <input type="text" id="zkolicina" />g
    <button type="button" onclick="izracun('zelenjava','zkolicina')">izračunaj</button><br>
  `;
  container.appendChild(clone);
}
```

I expect to have 7 buttons that clone the specific line once.

Comment: Your `cloneCode1()` and `cloneCode2()` functions are looking for certain DOM elements to be present on the current page (`#container1` and `#container2`). The mentioned error will occur if these elements don't exist.